# DB2 SQL error: SQLCODE: -206, SQLSTATE: 42703

Tags: db2

I am getting this JDBC exception. I googled it but the explanation was very abstract.

```
DB2 SQL error: SQLCODE: -206, SQLSTATE: 42703

com.misys.liq.jsqlaccess.adapter.jdbcadapter.util.JDBCAdapterException: com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.SqlException: DB2 SQL error: SQLCODE: -206, SQLSTATE: 42703,
```

Comment: I'm sure the DB2 reference manual contains a less abstract explanation.

Comment: you can have an attribute in your entity and this one isn't in your DB

Comment: You skipped posting the SQLERRMC portion of the error message. This should indicate the column of your select statement that doesn't exist in the database.

Comment: If you are using Hibernate api check the @Table(name = "table_name", schema="Schema_name")  annotation value

Comment: In my case, it was that the table in my from included a schema name, but I then referred to a column with just the table name, not including the schema. So, lesson learned: when you include a schema name in a table name, give the table name as a (redundant, but necessary) alias.

Answer (score 52):

That only means that an undefined column or parameter name was detected. The errror that DB2 gives should point what that may be:

```
DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, SQLERRMC=[THE_UNDEFINED_COLUMN_OR_PARAMETER_NAME], DRIVER=4.8.87
```

Double check your table definition. Maybe you just missed adding something.

I also tried google-ing this problem and saw this:

http://www.coderanch.com/t/515475/JDBC/databases/sql-insert-statement-giving-sqlcode